# ImportError : No module named json

Tags: python, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows subsystem for linux and I have set a virtual environment in my workspace.

I tried installing apache-airflow in the virtual environment and it got installed. But when I am trying to start the airflow webserver, I am getting the error

> ImportError- no module named json

I am not being able to resolve the issue. Please help. I am following the guide [Get started developing workflows with Apache Airflow](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2017/03/19/developing-workflows-with-apache-airflow/)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of version compatibility.

You should try compatible version of werkzeug using like "pip install werkzeug==0.15.4" or try to change version of flask.

Also you can refer some below link for reference.

[Apache Airflow : airflow initdb throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.json'; 'werkzeug.wrappers' is not a package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933523/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-throws-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-wer)
https://forum.astronomer.io/t/importerror-no-module-named-werkzeug-wrappers-json-werkzeug-wrappers-is-not-a-package/280