# airflow initdb in Docker throws ImportError: cannot import name 'import_string'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to dockerize `airflow`, my `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM python:3.5.2

RUN mkdir -p /src/airflow
RUN mkdir -p /src/airflow/logs
RUN mkdir -p /src/airflow/plugins
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN pip install psycopg2
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY airflow.cfg /src/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME /src/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/src"
RUN airflow initdb
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ./airflow-start.sh
```

while my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  airflow:
    container_name: airflow
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

The output of `$ docker-compose build` comes up like normal, every step executes and then

```
Step 12/14 : RUN airflow initdb
 ---> Running in 8b7ebe406978
[2020-04-21 10:34:21,419] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 17, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 59, in <module>
    from airflow.www.app import cached_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from flask_cache import Cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from werkzeug import import_string
ImportError: cannot import name 'import_string'
ERROR: Service 'airflow' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c airflow initdb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

`postgres` is running on host system. 
I have tried multiple ways but this keeps on happening. 
I even tried `puckel/docker-airflow` image and the same error occurred.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Project Structure:

```
root
  -airflow_dags
  -Dockerfile
  -docker-compose.yml
  -airflow-start.sh
  -airflow.cfg
```

In case it's relevant: [airflow-start.sh](https://textuploader.com/1lylw)

In `airflow.cfg`:

```
dags_folder = /src/airflow_dags/
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql://airflow:airflow@localhost:5432/airflow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is related to either a bug in airflow with the werkzeug package, or your requirements might be clobbering something.

I recommend checking the versions of airflow, flask, and werkzueg that are used in the environment. It may be that you need to pin the version of flask or werkzueg as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933523/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-throws-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-wer).

Answer (score 1):

If possible get your code running without touching docker ... run it directly on your host ...  of course this means your host ( your laptop or wherever you are executing your commands, could be a remote VPS debian box ) must have the same OS as your Dockerfile, I see in this case `FROM python:3.5.2` is actually using debian 8

Short of doing above launch a toy container which does nothing yet executes and lets you login to it to manually run your commands to aid troubleshooting ... so use following as this toy container's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5.2

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

so now issue this

```
docker build --tag saadi_now .   # creates image saadi_now
```

now launch that image

```
docker run -d  saadi_now  sleep infinity # launches container 

docker ps         #  lets say its container_id is b91f8cba6ed1
```

now login to that running container

```
docker exec -ti  b91f8cba6ed1 bash
```

cool so you are now inside the docker container so run the commands which were originally in the real Dockfile ... this sometime makes it easier to troubleshoot

one by one add to this toy Dockerfile your actual commands from the real Dockerfile and redo above until you discover the underlying issues

Comment: I tried it and got the same error at the same command. Even though I did not know how to do `network_mode: host` using that command line to make it access the host database but unfortunately, I did not even reach that point for that problem to occur. Also, I am using `MacOS` on which I am using a version of `airflow` & `python`, I've also used it on `Ubuntu` in the past but on `docker` it gives that error.